# Android - Update invalid token?

Tags: android, facebook, access-token

Is there is any possibility to update Facebook token without forcing user to log in again?
I have an app, when you login on device_1 and do the same on device_2, the token on device_1 is become invalid. I don't know why it happend? They should get exactly the same token, but they won't.

Returning to my question. Is there is any possibility to update invalid token or make facebook always return the same token if it not expired ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is any possibility to update invalid token or make facebook always return the same token if it not expired ?

To update an invalid token without having the user re-authenticate with Facebook, our [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) shows how to do that in step 8, call `extendAccessTokenIfNeeded()` in your `onResume()` method.  This will extend the user's access token in the background without any UI interference.  However, this requires the native Facebook app to be installed, but we are currently looking to provide an alternative.

You can also hit an endpoint to extend the access token yourself as seen in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) in scenario 4.

Also, our Android SDK will always return the same token if it is not expired by default.  However, if that token gets invalidated then it will be expired and you will have to retrieve a new token.

Comment: What do you mean "invalidated"? So if I understand it right, while I'm login on one device and after login on second device, token should be the same? So why I get every time different one? Thanks.